# Legend in Linechart- google-charts-react

Tags: reactjs, linechart

I´m using a Linechart from google-chart-react.

The problem is that I can´t change the legend position to the bottom, stays on the right.

I´ve tried:

```
    width={'70%'}
    height={'200'}
    chartType="Line"
    data={dats}

     options={{
      legend:'bottom',
      colors:['#95a0be','#90d6db'],
      width: 800,
      height: 300,
      series: {

        // Gives each series an axis name that matches the Y-axis below.
        0: { axis: 'Temps' },

      },....
```

Comment: I don't think it works that way.  I can only change it from left to right on my charts.

legend: { position: "left" }

Answer (score 2):

if you use react-google-charts, 
set chartType = "LineChart" and  legend: { position: 'bottom' }

```
  <Chart
    ...
    chartType="LineChart"
    options={{
      ...,
      legend: { position: 'bottom' },
    }}/>
```